# CAMEL - SALESFORCE Bulk API - set API version

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce

i'm creating a new Job with:

```
<to id="_slf_send2SC_to_salesforce_1" uri="salesforce:createJob"/>
```

in camelconfig.

After that, I created a new instance:

```
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo();
jobInfo.setOperation(OperationEnum.UPSERT);
jobInfo.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);
jobInfo.setObject(objName);
jobInfo.setExternalIdFieldName(externalId);
//Set API Version
jobInfo.setApiVersion("43.0");
```

But it seems that it doesn't work: api version on salesforce is always 34 (default version).

Could you help me?

Thanks,
Emanuele

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Yes, but i don't find nothing. In Salesforce doc i see that setApiVersion is read-only but i don't understand where I can change API version. Actually all batches use default_version (34).

Answer (score 0):

I solved in AnypointStudio.ini the variable vm. It should be:
-vm
C:\progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\

(without java.exe)

By
Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springboot, you can set the API version using the below property

camel.component.salesforce.api-version

Example:

camel.component.salesforce.api-version=38.0